# AWS RDS automated backup

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, backup, amazon-rds, database-backups

Can RDS automated backup be done in another region? I am seeing conflicting data from AWS:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implementing-a-disaster-recovery-strategy-with-amazon-rds/ says that automated backups are limited to single region.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/aws-backup-supports-cross-region-backup/ talks about AWS Backup and says that RDS has cross-region support.

I am now confused. Can someone please help? My goal is disaster recovery, as highlighted in the first link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first link you shared it is about the RDS snapshots (automatic snapshots) that are taken by the RDS service. These snapshots are only accessible within the single AWS region in which the snapshot was taken, however you can copy an automatic snapshot which will then make it a manual snapshot. From here you would then be able to copy the snapshot to another AWS region.

The second link is actually referring to the [AWS Backup service](https://aws.amazon.com/backup/) which is a service for centrally managing your backups. When this snapshot is taken the Backup service can actually handle the process of copying the snapshot to another region for you.

Its worth noting that AWS Backup Service is a more recent addition to AWS, whereas the automated snapshots for RDS have existed since the service launched.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Is it fair to conclude that for DR strategy, I would need to do two things: 1) Create automated snapshots. 2) Use AWS Backup to copy the snapshot in another region. If this is right, then I'd need both the services. I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Technically you can just use AWS Backup to fulfil this for you. It will create manual snapshots for you but the functionality will allow you to restore to a new database in exactly the same way as an automatic snapshot :)

Comment: However. you may want to also generate automatic snapshots too if you want to have point in time recovery for your local region :)

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am curious: would AWS Backup not give us point in time recovery, given that it will create manual snapshots for us at a predetermined interval?

Comment: So the difference is that automated snapshots have point in time recovery which allows you to choose a specific date time to restore from upto the second: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIT.html. The manual snapshots will be a point in time of when the snapshot is taken of course :)